# How to pass aws credentials

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I am very new to react and I am building a UI from where I can trigger AWS Batch jobs.
In this process, I am using @awws-sdk/client-batch

```
import { BatchClient, SubmitJobCommand, CancelJobCommand, DescribeJobsCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-batch"
```

Now I am facing difficulty when passing the credentials to AWS Batch.
I am not sure how to pass the AWS credentials from react js app.

The page here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-batch doesn't have any example on how to pass the AWS credentials as far as I found.

Should I use Amazon cognito for passing credentials or is there an easy way to do this?

My react app runs inside AWS private subnet and I am using Application Load Balancer to access the app.

Comment: You mentioned that your React app runs inside an AWS private subnet but React typically runs in the user's browser or mobile phone app, not in AWS. Can you clarify how/where you run the React client and what your back-end service looks like, assuming you have one?

Comment: There is a Docker image that runs on ECS and this points to an application load balancer (port 80) where I've the react code. I access the app via Route 53 URL. Sorry if this is bit confusing, but I am new to react/js stuff.

Comment: Worth reading: [Access your server-side resources with a user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-backend) and [Integrating Amazon Cognito authentication and authorization with web and mobile apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-integrate-apps.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have some options to supply your credentials to the SDK on the browser:

Some of these are more secure and others afford greater convenience while developing a script. Here are the ways you can supply your credentials in order of recommendation:

- Using Amazon Cognito Identity to authenticate users and supply credentials
- Using web federated identity
- Hard coded in the script

> According the AWS docs they do not recommend hard coding your AWS credentials in your scripts. Hard coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key.

Probably using Amazon Cognito or Web Federated Identity will be the way to go. We can get more info here: [Setting Credentials in a Web Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html).

And you can always create a back-end API using languages like Node.js or other one you like, and get the advantages of view/logic layers, you if you do not want to manage serves will can use a Serveless option Like API Gateway + AWS Lambda.