# How to create temporary AWS credentials for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-js

This is in response to the post in [How to pass aws credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77642932/how-to-pass-aws-credentials?noredirect=1#comment136882003_77642932)

I am trying to get temporary credentials that aws batch can assume by running a lambda script.
When I tested the lambda locally from AWS Console, I am getting error as below:

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"body": "{\"message\":\"Error retrieving temp credentials\",\"error\": 
{\"name\":\"ValidationError\",\"$fault\":\"client\",\"$metadata\": 
{\"httpStatusCode\":400,\"requestId\":\"6bf2751a-8bf8-4835-91a8- d5fd80dd5c6f\",\"attempts\":1,\"totalRetryDelay\":0},\"Type\":\"Sender\",\"Code\":\"ValidationError\",\"message\":\"1 validation error detected: Value null at 'roleArn' failed to satisfy 
constraint: Member must not be null\"}}"
}
```

My lambda function looks like this.

```
GenerateCredentialsLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Lambda function to generate temp credentials
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheFunctionBaseName}-v1'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheFunctionBaseName: !Ref FunctionBaseNameForLambdaEvent
    EphemeralStorage:
      Size: 10240
    Code:
      ZipFile: |
        const { STS, AssumeRoleCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-sts');
        exports.handler = async(event) => {
        const roleToAssumeArn = event.roleArn;
        const stsClient = new STS();
        try {
          //Assume the specified role to get temp credentials
          const assumedRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(new AssumeRoleCommand(
            {
              RoleArn: roleToAssumeArn,
              RoleSessionName: 'TemporarySession'
            }));
          //Extract temp credentials from AssumeRole Response
          const temporaryCredentials = assumedRoleResponse.Credentials;
      
          // Lambda function logic here
          return { 
            statusCode: 200, 
            body: JSON.stringify(temporaryCredentials)
          };
        } catch (error) {
          return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({message: "Error retrieving temp credentials", error})
          };
        }
      };
```

The LambdaExecution role referenced in the Lambda function is:

```
LambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'batch:SubmitJob'
                - 'batch:CancelJob'
                - 'batch:DescribeJobs'
              Resource: "*"
```

The role for generating temp credentials is:

```
GenerateTempCredentialsRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-ecs-credentials-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-ecs-credentials-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
              Resource: "*"
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-ec2-permissions-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: ['ec2:CreateNetworkInterface', 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces', 'ec2:AttachNetworkInterface',
            'ec2:DescribeInstances', 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface', 'logs:CreateLogGroup', 'logs:CreateLogStream',
            'logs:PutLogEvents']
              Resource: "*"
```

I bit unclear here. When lambda function runs, it expects an assumed role to perform the necessary steps (in this case generating temp credentials) and there is a role referenced in the lambda function (Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn).

I know this is something related to permission issue, but finding it hard to de-bug. Not an expert of AWS.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are wanting to use an AWS Lambda function to generate credentials rather than simply using an [AWS Batch execution IAM role - AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/execution-IAM-role.html)? The linked Question seems to be talking about React front-ends triggering AWS Batch jobs -- is that your requirement?

Comment: Your code appears to be failing because `roleToAssumeArn` (from `event.roleArn`) is null. So, print out the `event` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: I am bit confused here. Yes my requirement is about react front-ends triggering AWS Batch jobs. Is it enough to create AWS::IAM::Role with the mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/execution-IAM-role.html and then attach the role to the lambda function? I encountered "Credential is missing" when I tried to call AWS batch from react UI. So thought may be I should generate temp credentials with lambda and pass the temp credentials to the AWS batch via react. Again I am completely out of sight here. Thank you

Comment: Finally I am able to trigger AWS batch job from the code defined inside AWS::Lambda::Function. But my goal is to trigger the job from a react UI deployed in VPC. I already have an Application Load Balancer setup and integrated with R53 URL. Now I want to use this R53 URL and trigger the job which is now running successfully inside the lambda function. Any help to achieve this much appreciated.

Comment: Typically it works like this: your user authenticates to your back-end (options are Cognito or custom authentication), then does something in the UI to cause the UI to send an HTTP request to your back-end via API Gateway which triggers your Lambda function to execute. Your Lambda function has an associated IAM role which gives it permission to make AWS Batch API requests on behalf of the authenticated user.